# How to express variable in sed?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

```
$ VAR="this is working well"
$ sed -i "s/$/,$VAR/" my.txt

$ VAR="this/got/error"
$ sed -i "s/$/,$VAR/" my.txt
sed: -e expression #1, char 12: unknown option to `s
```

I have to put various kind of strings to $VAR.

Sometimes $VAR is not working with sed. Bcoz of special character.

How can I solve this problem with sed or regular expression?

Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` does not have the concept of variables, and the variable you're using is being interpreted by the shell before `sed` even sees it.  Because of this, if you want to use some sort of variable that can handle arbitrary text, you need to use a different tool which can do this.

For example, you could do this using Perl:

```
$ perl -i 's/$/,$ENV{VAR}/g' my.txt
```

or you could do it using `awk` and a temporary file:

```
$ awk '{ sub(/$/, "," ENVIRON["VAR"]); print }' my.txt > temp && mv temp my.txt
```

Note that using `sed -i`, regardless of whether it has this problem or not, is not portable.  On macOS, you must use `sed -i ''`, but that syntax does not work on Linux.  The `perl -i` invocation is portable to all systems using Perl, as would be an equivalent technique using `ruby -i`.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst `sed` tutorials typically use `/` as the search/replace delimiters, you can use many other symbols as delimiters.  For example `s/one/two/` could also be written as `s|one|two` or as `s#one#two`.

So - to solve your particular problem, the solution is simple - use a different delimiter.

```
$ cat file.txt
1
2
3
4

$ VAR="this is working well"
$ sed  's/$/,'"$VAR"'/' file.txt
1,this is working well
2,this is working well
3,this is working well
4,this is working well

$ VAR="this/got/error"
$ sed  's|$|,'"$VAR"'|' file
1,this/got/error
2,this/got/error
3,this/got/error
4,this/got/error
$
```